# JQuery.Deferred exception on filters

Tags: jquery, filter

I want to filter data from a object and assign those values. but value assigning should start once filtering is done.

> JQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

```js
var activitydata = function(allactivitiesObj) {
  allactivitiesObj.dataset = allactivitiesObj.dataset.map(function(mapdata) {
    var dataset2filter = dataset2.filter(function(data) {       
      return data.id === mapdata.id;      
    });          

    var dataset1filter = dataset1.filter(function(data) {        
      return data.id === mapdata.id;      
    });

    // before comes to this I need to make sure above filters are done. pls advice
    mapdata.dataset = dataset1filter[0].name;
    return mapdata;
  });
  return allactivitiesObj
}
```

`activitydata()` this will call inside init method.

Comment: The `filter()` call is synchronous so they will always complete before you last line of code. This seems like an XY question - why do you believe this is an issue?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan sometimes new.dataset = dataset1filter[0].name; is getting called before the filter.

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include a snippet which creates that behaviour. Without any async code I don't believe it's possible.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you check now

Comment: What's the content of `allactivitiesObj`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan its data object includd name , maplocation, id ... and I need to add   mapdata.dataset to it. but when this function runs sometimes it directly goes to   mapdata.dataset without passing filters

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan JQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: Also note that the error you edited in to the question will be caused if `dataset1filter[0]` is empty. It has nothing to do with the last line being executed out of order. That's simply not possible.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan but it points value inside my codeset. any suggestions or advices to resolve

Comment: You edited the comment - it originally said `role`. Now it says `name`. See my other comment above.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan dataset1filter has values but when refreshing the page this sometimes retuns data and sometimes not. that's why I thought  mapdata.dataset = dataset1filter[0].name; is execute before filtering.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ya it should 'name' role is typo i took from another func

Comment: Also, is this code block within a jQuery deferred object? Again, please add ***all relevant code to the question including the content of `allactivitiesObj`***. There is nothing we can do to help without seeing that. I wish you the best of luck.